# How to create masked array with a vector that separates sections of a 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

Let's say I have a standard 2d numpy array, let's call it my2darray with values. In this array there are two major sections. Let's say for each column, there is a specific row which separates "scenario1" and "scenario2". How can i create 2 masked arrays that represent the top section of my2darray and the bottom of my2darray. For example, i am interested in calculating the mean of the top half and the mean of the second half. One idea is to have a mask that is of the same shape as my2darray but that seems like a waste of memory. Is there a better idea? Let's say I have a vector, in which the length is equal to the number of rows in my2darray (in this case 6), i.e. I have

```
myvector=np.array([9, 15, 5,7,11,11])
```

I am using python 2.6 with numpy 1.5.0

[image: sample matrix]

Answer (score 0):

Using [`NumPy's broadcasted comparison`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we can create such a `2D` mask in a vectorized manner. Rest of the work is all about `sum-reduction` along the first axis for which we can take help from `np.einsum`. Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
N = my2darray.shape[0]
mask = myvector <= np.arange(N)[:,None]
uout = np.true_divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',my2darray,~mask),myvector)
lout = np.true_divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',my2darray,mask),N-myvector)
```

Sample run to verify results -

```
In [184]: N = my2darray.shape[0]
     ...: mask = myvector <= np.arange(N)[:,None]
     ...: uout = np.true_divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',my2darray,~mask),myvector)
     ...: lout = np.true_divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',my2darray,mask),N-myvector)
     ...: 

In [185]: uout
Out[185]: array([ 6. ,  4.6,  4. ,  0. ])

In [186]: [my2darray[:item,i].mean() for i,item in enumerate(myvector)]
Out[186]: [6.0, 4.5999999999999996, 4.0, 0.0] # Loopy version results

In [187]: lout
Out[187]: array([ 5.2       ,  4.        ,  2.66666667,  2.        ])

In [188]: [my2darray[item:,i].mean() for i,item in enumerate(myvector)]
Out[188]: [5.2000000000000002, 4.0, 2.6666666666666665, 2.0] # Loopy version
```

---

Another potentially faster way would be to calculate the summations for the upper mask, store it and from it, subtract the sum along the first axis along the entire length of the `2D` input array. This could be then used for the calculation of the lower part average. Thus, after we store `N` and calculate `mask`, we would have -

```
usum = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',my2darray,~mask)
uout = np.true_divide(usums,myvector)
lout = np.true_divide(my2darray.sum(0) - usums,N-myvector)
```